# How to set specific user profile path on EC2 Windows server?

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012-r2, user-profile

I want to create a new local user on EC2 Windows 2012 R2 server and specify its profile folder explicitly. I do the following

```
net user SomeUser Pwd /ADD /HOMEDIR:C:\Users\SomeUser /PROFILEPATH:C:\Users\SomeUser
```

The user has been created successfully but when I logged in via RDP the profile was actually set to C:\Users\TEMP

What's going on?